# Model Entity Representation of an Organigram

Tags: database-design

I'm new to database and I'm trying to represent and organigram of a family (Great Grand father, Grand father, father, etc) using MER (Model Entity Relationship), and I'm quite confused on if I should be represent them hierarchical or if I should represent them as Individual entities.

Comment: We need more info to give an accurate answer. Are you you simply creating an ER diagram or are you creating a DB design? e.g. normalization, constraints, etc.?

Comment: I'm just doing an ER diagram

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do as follows. Create a **Person** entity with data fields such as **id, name, address** and create another entity **Person-Relationship** with data fields such as **pr-id, rel-type** with instance of grandfather, father, etc...The physical data model might look as follows,

```
pr_type     
{      
     pr_id(pk), pr_type    
}     

person      
{      
     person_id(pk), pr_id(fk),  person_name   
}
```

Here, **pr_type** data field may contain the entities such as **great grandfather, grandfather, father, son, etc...**

I hope this will give some understanding. Thanks.